# List Box data template with style - On tap change the background color

Tags: c#, wpf, windows-phone-8, listbox, windows-phone

I am working on `Windows Phone 8 application,` I have List box with Items in it, for the items i have used DataTemplate, now i have a style as well which i have applied to List as ItemContainerStyle.

Basically this is how it is , i have a list item with default color say grey,now when i tap on that item the color grey should change to red, so that it indicates to user that he has selected that item.

My code works but its not applying as background, instead its being applied as foreground.

List box :

```
<ListBox Name="listBox" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
         ItemTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}"
         ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle}"/>
```

Data template:

```
 <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate">
            <Border  
                    Background="#e3e8f0"
                    Margin="0,2,0,0" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                <Grid       Width="Auto"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <TextBlock
                                           Text="{Binding Path=Text}" 
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                           Padding="10,25,10,25"
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap"
                                           MinHeight="80"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                           TextAlignment="Center"
                                           Style="{StaticResource TextStyle}"
                                           Foreground="Black"/>
</Grid>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
```

ListBoxItemStyle:

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseLeave">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To="0.75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".55" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="contentPresenter"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".75" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="fillColor2"/>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility" Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualElement">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Visibility>Visible</Visibility>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" 
                                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}" 
                                            Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" 
                                            HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"
                                            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
                                            VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor" Fill="#d2f2f9" IsHitTestVisible="False" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Margin="0,3" Opacity="0"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="fillColor2" Fill="#d2f2f9" IsHitTestVisible="False" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" Margin="0,3" Opacity="0"/>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="FocusVisualElement" RadiusY="1" RadiusX="1" StrokeThickness="1" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="0,3"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to override `ControlTemplate` for that. Override system highlight brush for your ListBox by placing it under ListBox resources if all you want is to change highlight brush for your listBox.

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.Resources>
     <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.HighlightBrushKey}"
                      Color="Red"/>
  </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: i have placed your code, its giving me errors, can you please modify  my code with yours?

Comment: it says x:static was not found

Answer (score 1):

Update: Okay, since you didn't specify explicitly that you are using `Silverlight` which is a subset of `WPF` framework, not all of its `API` is the same.

For windows phone you want to do something like this

```
<Style x:Key="ListBoxItemStyle1" TargetType="ListBoxItem">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Transparent"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Top"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Border x:Name="LayoutRoot" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalAlignment}" VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalAlignment}">
                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background" Storyboard.TargetName="LayoutRoot">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{StaticResource TransparentBrush}"/>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0" To=".5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity" Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="SelectionStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Unselected"/>
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="ContentContainer"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground"
                                Duration="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame  KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="White"/>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
                                Storyboard.TargetName="border"
                                Storyboard.TargetProperty="Background"
                                Duration="0">
                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame  KeyTime="0">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="YellowGreen"/>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>

 </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                         <StackPanel x:Name="border" Orientation="Horizontal">
                             <CheckBox x:Name="checkBox" IsChecked="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, 
 Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}" DataContext="{TemplateBinding
 IsSelected}" Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource
 BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"
 HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding
 HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
                         <ContentControl x:Name="ContentContainer" ontentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentTemplate}"
 Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding
 Foreground}" HorizontalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding
 HorizontalContentAlignment}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
 VerticalContentAlignment="{TemplateBinding
 VerticalContentAlignment}"/>
                         </StackPanel>
                     </Border>
                 </ControlTemplate>
             </Setter.Value>
         </Setter>
    </Style>
```

then set the style for the `ListBox`

```
<ListBox x:Name="databoundListBox" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource ListBoxItemStyle1}" SelectionMode="Multiple"/>
```

Comment: It says that static is not supported in silverlight project, the tage static does not exist in namespace :http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml

Comment: After adding your style the list items are not displaying at all

Comment: @user2056563 Please see my edited answer apparently, the code was chopped off.

Comment: can you please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22578128/list-box-with-multiple-data-template-style-for-selected-item